# Can I replace angular.copy with _lodash and would it be more efficient?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I am doing the following:

```
$scope.grid.backup = angular.copy(result);
```

Is this something that I could do with _lodash and does anyone have any ideas if the performance would be any different ?

**Update:**

Hard to imagine what can be unclear about:

Can I replace angular.copy with _lodash and would it be more efficient?

So for those who just don't understand I will add the word "_.clone"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**_.clone(value, [isDeep=false], [callback], [thisArg])**](http://lodash.com/docs#clone)

```
 $scope.grid.backup = _.clone(result);
```

Comment: `angular.copy` creates a deep copy.

Comment: Any idea if this would be more efficient than the way Angular does it. I keep reading about how efficient _lodash is.

Comment: @Melina, As per [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/angular-copy-vs-lodash-clone) **_.clone** is fastest

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder why the question was put on hold. I can only assume those putting it on hold do not have a knowledge of AngularJS and _lodash.

Comment: @Melina Question is quite clear. I have been asking it 100 times to myself having no time for testing this.

Comment: If you need a deep copy, according to this https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/334/0/angular-copy-vs-lodash-copy the angular solution is faster. If you need a shallow copy, it seems reasonable that `_.clone()` would be fastest.